# RecyclerView scroll position

Tags: android, mysql

I have a RecyclerView includes 20 items from my rest api. When I add a new item to database, the first item in my list disappear and new one will add into the end of list by using mysql `LIMIT 0,20`

I want when I'm in the list and new item added, the scroll position doesn't change, so I used `onSaveInstansceState` before the adapter and `onRestoreInstanceState` after it. but as you can understand the new list has a difference with the older and that's the item position.So the list scroll one item more from its state.

How can I prevent this or is there another solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the scroll position to change when adding an item, use `notifyItemInserted()`.

```
// adapter

void addNewItem(Item item) {
    itemList.add(item);
    notifyItemInserted(itemList.size() - 1);
}
```

Comment: I don't add items dynamically in android code , I just add the item in php code and remove the oldest one and then update whole list in android.